# How to average values based on location proximity

Tags: sql, database, google-maps, gps

I have an SQL table with geo-tagged values (Longitude, Latitude,  value). The table is accumulated quickly and has thousands entries. Therefore, querying the table for values in some area return very large data-set.

I would like to know the way to average value with close location proximity to one value, here is an illustration:

Table:

```
Long            lat           value
10.123001       53.567001      10
10.123002       53.567002      12
10.123003       53.567003      18
10.124003       53.568003      13
```

lets say my current location is 10.123004, 53.567004. If I am querying for the values near by I will get the four raws with values 10, 12, 18, and 13. This works if the data-set is relatively small. If the data is large I would like to query sql for rounded location  (10.123, 53.567) and need sql to return something like

```
Long            lat           value
10.123       53.567      10 (this is the average of 10, 12, and 18)
10.124       53.568      13
```

Is this possible? how we can average large data set based on locations?

Is sql database is the right choice in the first place?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "average of all data of rounded location)"

Comment: I re-wrote the question, I hope it is now little more clear than before

Comment: The average of 10, 12, and 18 is 40/3, which is about 13.3.  Is this a typo or do you mean something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` rounded columns, and the AVG aggregate function should work fine for this:

```
SELECT ROUND(Long, 3) Long, 
       ROUND(Lat, 3) Lat, 
       AVG(value) 
 FROM Table
 GROUP BY ROUND(Long, 3), ROUND(Lat, 3)
```

Add a WHERE clause to filter as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some rough pseudocode that might be a start. You need to provide the proper precision arguments for the round function in the dialect of SQL you are using for your project, so understand that the 3 I provide as the second argument to Round is the number of decimals of precision to which the number is rounded, as indicated by your original post.

Select round(lat,3),round(long,3),avg(value)
Group by round(lat,3),round(long,3)

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the rounding approach is the boundary conditions -- what happens when points are close to the bounday.

However, for the neighborhood of a given point it is better to use something like:

```
select *
from table
where long between @MyLong - @DeltaLong and @MyLong + @DeltaLong and
      lat between @MyLat - @DeltaLat and @MyLat + @DeltaLat
```

For this, you need to define @DeltaLong and @DeltaLat.

Rounding works fine for summarization, if that is your problem.